# Another "svn: Repository moved permanently to please relocate" issue

Tags: apache, svn, http

I have a bunch of projects on the same server. This server is hosting both the SVN repos and the actual web projects. I'd like to have this structure:

```
project1.server.com - with doc root to /var/www/html/project1/public
project2.server.com - with doc root to /var/www/html/project2/public
project3.server.com - with doc root to /var/www/html/project3/public
```

And be able to access every SVN repo with this URLs

```
svn.server.com/project1 - with repo root at /var/www/svn/project1/
svn.server.com/project2 - with repo root at /var/www/svn/project2/
svn.server.com/project3 - with repo root at /var/www/svn/project3/
```

My current configs are:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName project1.server.com
        DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/project1/public"
        RewriteEngine off
        <Location />
                RewriteEngine on
                RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
                RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
                RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css)$ /index.php
        </Location>
</VirtualHost>

# ... similar <VirtualHost> tags here for the other web subdomains

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName svn.server.com
        <Location />
                Deny from all
        </Location>

        <Location /project1>
                Allow from all
                AuthType Basic
                AuthUserFile /etc/svn-auth-conf
                Require valid-user
                DAV svn
                SVNPath /var/www/svn/project1
                AuthName "Project 1 - Development Repository"
                AuthzSVNAccessFile /etc/svn-acl-conf
        </Location>

# ... similar <Location> tags for the other repos

</VirtualHost>
```

If I change the DocumentRoots to something different like /var/www/html/project1-site/public this works well, so I'm pretty sure that what's happening is [this](http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#http-301-error):

> It's also possible that you have an object in the web root which has the same name as your repository URL. For example, imagine your web server's document root is /var/www and your Subversion repository is located at /home/svn/repo. You then configure Apache to serve the repository at http://server.com/myrepo. If you then create the directory /var/www/myrepo/ this will cause a 301 error to occur.

But I would really like to keep the directory structure like I showed above. What should I do to get it working? I want to have it like this since it's the tidier structure I could come up with. So ideas are also accepted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try changing the port of the SVN v-host (I think SVN usually uses `3690`). Right now you're using the same root path (`Location /`) and same port (`80`) for both protocols, so Apache can't differentiate the two kinds of requests.

Some more info here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Subversion#Repository_access

Note that your SVN clients will also have to use this port. Not sure if that's ok for you.

Comment: Good idea. But that would complicate the client connection a bit. I'm still not sure of why `http://project.server.com` and `http://svn.server.com/project` are two nondifferentiable requests.

Comment: I prefer to change the port for clarity, but if that's not an option, you can change the domain (part before the colon). E.g. `<VirtualHost project1.server.com:80>` and `<VirtualHost svn.server.com:80>`. The apache docs on this are [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#virtualhost) if you need more detail.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your repository in the document root you can access it with the url
**svn+ssh://<absolute_path_to_repository>**
instead of 
**http://<document_root_relative_path_to_repository>**
You need ssh access and credentials.